# Frequent BSOD on Windows 10 VNC Server

Tags: realvnc

I'm using [RealVNC server](https://www.realvnc.com/en/) v6.7.2 x64 home edition and ever since I started using it, my laptop that is the VNC server has been randomly displaying a "blue screen of death" and then shutting down.  This is happening almost daily where as this laptop almost never BSOD'ed before.

Are there any settings in VNC server that might cause or help prevent the "server" from crashing?  I realize this could potentially be an issue totally unrelated to VNC Server, but it seems like there's a correlation between it's use and the now frequent BSODs.

My server laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad P51 running Windows 10 Enterprise (version 20H2, build 19042.630) and is fully patched.

Comment: You could maybe try another VNC variant.

Comment: FWIW: My experience is that BSOD is most often caused by hardware problems; e.g. oxidized connector on RMA-module - remedy in that case; use pencil eraser to clean the connector.

Comment: FYI: I've paid for a home RealVNC license because I tried multiple other services and they weren't as good or where unaffordable.  Unfortunately, RealVNC doesn't provide support for home user licenses and states that questions should be asked here on StackExchange with a "realvnc" tag.